# Install php-mcrypt on CentOS 6

Tags: php, centos

I have been trying to install php-mcrypt for a while now. Everytime I get the "No package php-mcrypt available." returned to me. Here's what I've tried:

```
root@ip-********** [~]# yum install php-mcrypt --enablerepo=centosplus (<- both with and without this)
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
* base: p3plmirror01.prod.phx3.secureserver.net
* centosplus: p3plmirror01.prod.phx3.secureserver.net
* epel: mirrors.solfo.com
* extras: p3plmirror01.prod.phx3.secureserver.net
* updates: p3plmirror01.prod.phx3.secureserver.net
centosplus                                               | 3.5 kB     00:00
centosplus/primary_db                                    | 746 kB     00:00
Setting up Install Process
No package php-mcrypt available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

I have made sure to install the EPEL repository. At this point I'm just stumped. I've followed EVERY tutorial I've found online and get the same error.

Notes: [GoDaddy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Go_Daddy) [VPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_server), [CentOS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CentOS) 6.4 64-bit, mcrypt installed without a hitch, but no php-mcrypt.

Comment: My past few days was nightmare for me because of Go daddy VPS. Can I contact u, just in case we can share knowledge.. thanks

Comment: It is best not to use mcrypt, it is abandonware, has not been updated in years and does not support standard PKCS#7 (née PKCS#5) padding, only non-standard null padding that can't even be used with binary data. mcrypt had many outstanding [bugs](https://sourceforge.net/p/mcrypt/bugs/) dating back to 2003. Instead consider using [defuse](https://github.com/defuse/php-encryption), it is being maintained and is correct.

Comment: Mcrypt is still heavy used in a lot of third party applications and frameworks. So unless defuse can seamlessly replace mcrypt without having to re-code Its not currently an option. But I will definitely keep that in mind for future reference!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was able to figure this out; it was a lot simpler then I thought. Under the WHM manager go to: Home >> Software >> EasyApache (Apache Update) >> There you have two options "Build Profile" or "Customize Based On Profile". I went Customize to keep my current config then followed the instructions on the page.

Eventually there was a place to add and remove php modules. There you will  find ever module under the sun. Just select the one you want and rebuild the profile. It was really that simple.

Comment: it did help me. VOte up for u. But wait. It seems to me, everything have to be install via EasyApache. yum commmand is kinda disabled or something. Can you please share your experience on that

Comment: @PhamHuyAnh that was a long time ago. From what i can remember i was able to do it all through the cpanel backend like i said above. You should have to run any yum commands.

Comment: I have managed to survived the pain with Godaddy VPS. Had to use both EasyApache and yum... Thanks

Comment: Awesome help. I tried with all the commands and also via .rpm package but not worked with anyone but when I tried with EasyApache then it worked like a charm. Great help for this one.... :)

Comment: Neither of the top answers worked for me. This one did.

Answer (score 115):

I had the same issue, and found the previous suggestions gave me enough info to get it working on my server. The following is what I did:

1) Install EPEL repository (From: http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/installing-rhel-epel-repo-on-centos-5x-or-6x):

```
wget http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
wget http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/remi-release-6.rpm
sudo rpm -Uvh remi-release-6*.rpm epel-release-6*.rpm
```

2) Install it via:

```
yum update
yum install php-mcrypt*
```

The `yum update` updated the repository reference on my server then the 2nd command got what I needed :)

3) Restart your webserver. For my apache install I did:

```
service httpd restart
```

Comment: In some cases, do you need to edit the "mcrypt.ini" file (sudo nano /etc/php.d/mcrypt.ini) and add the line "extension=/usr/lib64/php/modules/mcrypt.so". Then restart the httpd service.

Comment: same problem when i was trying to install opencart which required mcrypt, that solved it !

Comment: As a complete command line novice this worked for me without a hitch - many thanks!

Comment: I had to run: `yum install php53-mcrypt`

Comment: this doesn't work for php 5.4, because `yum --disableplugin=priorites info php-mcrypt` shows only php-mcrypt for php 5.3.3 as available (and in my case, also installed)

Comment: You only need the epel repository. The remi repository is not really needed if you only want to install mcrypt.

Comment: Must do restart httpd service after the installation, then it will take affect.

Comment: For me, this worked : `yum install php-mcrypt*` and then, restart httpd service : `service httpd restart`

Answer (score 26):

For me the answer was:

1) Get the Repos from

```
wget http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
wget http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/remi-release-6.rpm
sudo rpm -Uvh remi-release-6*.rpm epel-release-6*.rpm
```

2) Install it via:

```
sudo yum update
sudo yum install php-mcrypt*
```

3) Edit the mcrypt.ini

```
sudo nano /etc/php.d/mcrypt.ini
```

add this

```
extension=/usr/lib64/php/modules/mcrypt.so
```

Finally
4) Restart your webserver:

```
sudo service httpd restart
```

I run this steps in CentOS 6.3 (64) on Azure From Microsoft Linux image

Hope it helps you.

Best Regards.

Comment: it was not necessary, at least for me, to change the extension.

Comment: Awesome! Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 11):

Updated Answer for centos 7

```
 ## RHEL/CentOS 7 64-Bit ##
 # wget http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/beta/7/x86_64/epel-release-7-0.2.noarch.rpm
 # rpm -ivh epel-release-7-0.2.noarch.rpm
```

For CentOS 6

```
 ## RHEL/CentOS 6 32-Bit ##
 # wget http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/i386/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
 # rpm -ivh epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm

 ## RHEL/CentOS 6 64-Bit ##
 # wget http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
 # rpm -ivh epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
```

Install

```
 yum install php-mcrypt
```

**Edit**: See comments for updated repositories.

Comment: `http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/beta/7/x86_64/epel-release-7-0.2.noarch.rpm` is not work...

Comment: Yes, the link above is not working as it's the beta one. Just so I avoid pasting a link that will become outdated soon, it's probably best if you go to http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/x86_64/e/ and download the latest version of epel-release

Comment: Just use `yum -y install epel-release && yum -y install php-mcrypt`

Answer (score 10):

```
yum install php-mcrypt.x86_64
```

worked for me instead of

```
yum install php-mcrypt
```

Answer (score 5):

I got too much problem in installing php-mcrypt using epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm. It has some dependency problem.

Then I tried in different way.

Get the php-mcrypt using "wget ftp://ftp.univie.ac.at/systems/linux/fedora/epel/6/x86_64/php-mcrypt-5.3.3-3.el6.x86_64.rpm" command.

Then install libmcrypt

ftp://ftp.pbone.net/mirror/download.fedora.redhat.com/pub/fedora/epel/6/x86_64/libmcrypt-2.5.8-9.el6.x86_64.rpm

The installed php-mcrypt using following command

```
yum install php-mcrypt-5.3.3-3.el6.x86_64.rpm
```

Answer (score 3):

If php_mcrypt installed on 64bit but reported missing by an installer, check the extension path:

vi /etc/php.d/mcrypt.ini

> ```
> ; Enable mcrypt extension module
> ;extension=module.so
> extension=/usr/lib64/php/modules/mcrypt.so
> ```

Answer (score 3):

To install mcrypt from http://namhuy.net/641/centos-6-install-mcrypt-for-phpmyadmin.html

i386

```
rpm -Uvh http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/i386/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
```

x86_64

```
http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
```

then just use yum command to install the mcrypt package

```
yum install php-mcrypt
```

Answer (score 3):

The best way is to:

```
wget http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/php-mcrypt-5.3.3-3.el6.x86_64.rpm
yum localinstall php-mcrypt-5.3.3-3.el6.x86_64.rpm

wget http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/libmcrypt-2.5.8-9.el6.x86_64.rpm
yum localinstall libmcrypt-2.5.8-9.el6.x86_64.rpm
```

or go to: http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/ to match your version 
check from your info.php that is ok -- done!

Comment: Also from my point of view this is the best way. I don't want to add the whole epel repository on my centOS.

Comment: Be careful to keep your version updated if you do this.

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways you can address this:

- Download php-mcrypt from fedora:
  http://injustfiveminutes.wordpress.com/2012/11/23/install-php-mcrypt-extension-on-rhel-6/
- Check if you're facing a known bug with a wrongly packaged php-mcrypt extension:
  http://www.sterndata.com/blog/phymyadmin-mcrypt-and-centos-6-mcrypt-extension-missing-solved

Comment: I was able to install the libmcrypt but not php-mcrypt i  still get the error:

root@ip-50-62-78-213 [/tmp]# yum localinstall php-mcrypt-5.3.3-1.el6.x86_64.rpm
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Setting up Local Package Process
Examining php-mcrypt-5.3.3-1.el6.x86_64.rpm: php-mcrypt-5.3.3-    1.el6.x86_64
Nothing to do

Comment: Thanks, Filippos. I was looking for a way to install php-mcrypt without the need to upgrade PHP (5.3.3) and the download from fedora did the trick.

Answer (score 2):

For me I had to add the EPEL repository. It is where my php-mcrypt came from:

```
[root@system ~]$ repoquery -i php-mcrypt

Name        : php-mcrypt
Version     : 5.3.3
Release     : 1.el6
Architecture: i686
Size        : 39225
Packager    : Fedora Project
Group       : Development/Languages
URL         : http://www.php.net/
Repository  : epel <----------
Summary     : Standard PHP module provides mcrypt library support
Source      : php-extras-5.3.3-1.el6.src.rpm
Description :
Standard PHP module provides mcrypt library support
```

You can enable the EPEL repo with the instructions here:

http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL

Comment: The EPEL helped me get get it working on my server, but the link on how to install EPEL wasn't much help. I gave a answer lower down which shows how to install it and cites the reference I used.

Answer (score 1):

installing php-mcrypt from Repoforge worked for me perfectly. Just add Repoforge from http://repoforge.org/ and simply run yum install php-mcrypt.

Comment: Thank you! It is very helpful. + extension=/usr/lib64/php/modules/mcrypt.so from previous message

Answer (score 1):

For me, this worked :
`yum install php-mcrypt*`
and then, restart httpd service
`service httpd restart`

I tryed @VenomFangs solution but the first step was not needed for me. I already had a newer EPEL version installed. So, the first step following was not usefull, I backed to the snapshot I did before doing modifications and I just used the install and restart above commands.

`wget http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm`
`wget http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/remi-release-6.rpm`
`sudo rpm -Uvh remi-release-6*.rpm epel-release-6*.rpm`

CentOS Linux release 7.2.1511 (Core)

PS : I know this is not the subject, but if somebody needs it, the keyword can help. I needed to do this because of this error on prestashop. Two keywords I would be glad to use to find this informations are : "php_mycrypt.dll" "php_mcrypt.dll"
`Fatal error: Call to undefined function mcrypt_encrypt() in /classes/Rijndael.php on line 46`

EDIT 10/06/2016 :
Another Prestashop solution to try in "Advanced Parameters", "Performance", "Ciphering" (FR : Chiffrement), `"Use the custom BlowFish class."` instead of `"Use Rijndael with mcrypt lib. (you must install the Mcrypt extension)."`

Answer (score 1):

First find out your PHP version. In my case 5.6.

`php --version`

`PHP 5.6.27 (cli) (built: Oct 15 2016 21:31:59) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies`

Then:

`sudo yum search mcrypt`

And choose the best one for your version from the list, I used `php56w-mcrypt`.

````
  $ sudo yum search mcrypt
  Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
  Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile

  ..... output truncated ....

libmcrypt-devel.i686 : Development libraries and headers for libmcrypt
libmcrypt-devel.x86_64 : Development libraries and headers for libmcrypt
libtomcrypt-devel.i686 : Development files for libtomcrypt
libtomcrypt-devel.x86_64 : Development files for libtomcrypt
libtomcrypt-doc.noarch : Documentation files for libtomcrypt
php-mcrypt.x86_64 : Standard PHP module provides mcrypt library support
php55w-mcrypt.x86_64 : Standard PHP module provides mcrypt library support

# either of these are fine:
php56-php-mcrypt.x86_64 : Standard PHP module provides mcrypt library support
php56w-mcrypt.x86_64 : Standard PHP module provides mcrypt library support

php70-php-mcrypt.x86_64 : Standard PHP module provides mcrypt library support
php70w-mcrypt.x86_64 : Standard PHP module provides mcrypt library support
php71-php-mcrypt.x86_64 : Standard PHP module provides mcrypt library support
libmcrypt.i686 : Encryption algorithms library
libmcrypt.x86_64 : Encryption algorithms library
libtomcrypt.i686 : A comprehensive, portable cryptographic toolkit
libtomcrypt.x86_64 : A comprehensive, portable cryptographic toolkit
mcrypt.x86_64 : Replacement for crypt()
```
````

Finally:

`sudo service httpd restart`

Comment: you saved my day...    
Step 1. sudo yum search mcrypt      
Step 2. sudo yum install php70-mcrypt.x86_64
Step 3 Restart apache

Answer (score 0):

I was having same issue in centos 6.5

Finaly solution below worked for me

-go to http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/
-search for php-mcrypt(http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/php-mcrypt-5.3.3-3.el6.x86_64.rpm)
-execute wget http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/php-mcrypt-5.3.3-3.el6.x86_64.rpm
-rpm -ivh php-mcrypt-5.3.3-3.el6.x86_64.rpm

if there are any dependencies you can download same using http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/

Answer (score 0):

For php 7 to install mcrypt run:

Centos:
sudo yum install php7.0-mcrypt to install

On Ubuntu:
sudo apt-get install php7.0-mcrypt

Answer (score 0):

If you want to recompile `PHP` with `mcrypt` enable.

1.
Insatll `mcrypt`. `libmcrypt-devel` is from Third Party Repositories EPEL, so you should:

```
yum --enablerepo=extras install epel-release
yum install libmcrypt-devel
```

2.
Append `--with-mcrypt` to your `./configure` arguments:

```
./configure --with-mcrypt
```

3.
Build and install:

```
make & make install
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try**

```
yum clean all
yum remove epel-release
yum install epel-release
```

**and finally**

```
yum install php-mcrypt
```