# Error trying to install the mcrypt extension

Tags: php, centos, mcrypt

I'm running PHP Version 5.4.23 under [CentOS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CentOS) 6.4 x64 and am trying to install mcrypt extension:

```
[root@user]# yum install php-mcrypt*
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: ftp.osuosl.org
 * epel: ftp.osuosl.org
 * extras: ftp.osuosl.org
 * updates: ftp.osuosl.org
Setting up Install Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-mcrypt.x86_64 0:5.3.3-3.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php(zend-abi) = 20090626 for package: php-mcrypt-5.3.3-3.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: php(api) = 20090626 for package: php-mcrypt-5.3.3-3.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libmcrypt.so.4()(64bit) for package: php-mcrypt-5.3.3-3.el6.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package libmcrypt.x86_64 0:2.5.8-9.el6 will be installed
---> Package php-mcrypt.x86_64 0:5.3.3-3.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php(zend-abi) = 20090626 for package: php-mcrypt-5.3.3-3.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: php(api) = 20090626 for package: php-mcrypt-5.3.3-3.el6.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: php-mcrypt-5.3.3-3.el6.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: php(api) = 20090626
           Installed: php-common-5.4.23-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (@remi)
               php(api) = 20100412-x86-64
           Available: php-common-5.3.3-26.el6.x86_64 (base)
               php(api) = 20090626
           Available: php-common-5.3.3-27.el6_5.x86_64 (updates)
               php(api) = 20090626
Error: Package: php-mcrypt-5.3.3-3.el6.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: php(zend-abi) = 20090626
           Installed: php-common-5.4.23-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (@remi)
               php(zend-abi) = 20100525-x86-64
           Available: php-common-5.3.3-26.el6.x86_64 (base)
               php(zend-abi) = 20090626
           Available: php-common-5.3.3-27.el6_5.x86_64 (updates)
               php(zend-abi) = 20090626
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17109818/install-php-mcrypt-on-centos6

Comment: I tried all those methods but same error happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the php-mcrypt version in your yum library is for PHP 5.3.3.

Your PHP version is 5.4.23. Try this: `http://rpms.southbridge.ru/rhel6/php-5.4/x86_64/php-mcrypt-5.4.23-1.el6.remi.x86_64.rpm`

Download the RPM from above and run `rpm -ivh <name>`

Make sure you have libmcrypt installed separately though. Yum installs all dependencies, so if you were using yum it would've installed libmcrypt