# mCrypt installation failed CentOs 7

Tags: php, centos7, mcrypt, webmin, virtualmin

I have to install mCrypt.
I've chcecked those methods:
[Install php-mcrypt on CentOS 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17109818/install-php-mcrypt-on-centos-6)

And not worked for me. After I've tried to use this:
sudo yum install epel-release
sudo yum install libmcrypt-devel

*If you are running the default PHP installation you will want to run the following command as well...*

sudo yum install php-mcrypt

And got this:

```
[root@development ~]# sudo yum install libmcrypt-devel
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: ftp.ciril.fr
 * epel: mirror.nl.leaseweb.net
 * extras: ftp.ciril.fr
 * updates: ftp.ciril.fr
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package libmcrypt-devel.x86_64 0:2.5.8-9.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libmcrypt = 2.5.8-9.el6 for package: libmcrypt-devel-2.5.8-9.el6.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package libmcrypt.i686 0:2.5.8-9.el6 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error:  Multilib version problems found. This often means that the root
       cause is something else and multilib version checking is just
       pointing out that there is a problem. Eg.:

         1. You have an upgrade for libmcrypt which is missing some
            dependency that another package requires. Yum is trying to
            solve this by installing an older version of libmcrypt of the
            different architecture. If you exclude the bad architecture
            yum will tell you what the root cause is (which package
            requires what). You can try redoing the upgrade with
            --exclude libmcrypt.otherarch ... this should give you an error
            message showing the root cause of the problem.

         2. You have multiple architectures of libmcrypt installed, but
            yum can only see an upgrade for one of those architectures.
            If you don't want/need both architectures anymore then you
            can remove the one with the missing update and everything
            will work.

         3. You have duplicate versions of libmcrypt installed already.
            You can use "yum check" to get yum show these errors.

       ...you can also use --setopt=protected_multilib=false to remove
       this checking, however this is almost never the correct thing to
       do as something else is very likely to go wrong (often causing
       much more problems).

       Protected multilib versions: libmcrypt-2.5.8-9.el6.i686 != libmcrypt-2.5.8-13.el7.x86_64
[root@development ~]# sudo yum install php-mcrypt
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: ftp.ciril.fr
 * epel: epel.mirrors.ovh.net
 * extras: ftp.ciril.fr
 * updates: ftp.ciril.fr
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-mcrypt.x86_64 0:5.3.3-3.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php(zend-abi) = 20090626 for package: php-mcrypt-5.3.3-3.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: php(api) = 20090626 for package: php-mcrypt-5.3.3-3.el6.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: php-mcrypt-5.3.3-3.el6.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: php(api) = 20090626
           Installed: php-common-5.4.16-36.el7_1.x86_64 (@updates)
               php(api) = 20100412-64
           Available: php-common-5.4.16-23.el7_0.3.x86_64 (base)
               php(api) = 20100412-64
Error: Package: php-mcrypt-5.3.3-3.el6.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: php(zend-abi) = 20090626
           Installed: php-common-5.4.16-36.el7_1.x86_64 (@updates)
               php(zend-abi) = 20100525-64
           Available: php-common-5.4.16-23.el7_0.3.x86_64 (base)
               php(zend-abi) = 20100525-64
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
[root@development ~]#
```

Any help?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

you can try to search for the same

```
yum search php-mcrypt
```

and follow these steps:

```
yum clean all
yum update

yum install php7*-mcrypt
```

or

```
yum install php*-mcrypt
```