# php-mcrypt extension is not getting loaded

Tags: php, magento, centos6, mcrypt

`php-mcrypt` extension is not getting loaded. It doesn't seems to be working.

I am using an Cent OS server.

I already tried many solution but didn't found any valuable.

Also php5enmod command is not working to enable an `php-mcrypt` extension.

I need this because while in the Magento checkout page it shows an error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function mcrypt_module_open() in
>   /var/www/html/yms/lib/Varien/Crypt/Mcrypt.php on line 63

So need to get installed `php-mcrypt` extension.

Comment: Possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17109818/install-php-mcrypt-on-centos-6

Comment: @Mattia I did prefer that but doesn't work.

Comment: You add the extension in your php.ini ?

Comment: Try this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17109818/install-php-mcrypt-on-centos-6

Answer (score 0):

Install mcrypt by using this command "yum install php55-php-mcrypt" for Cent OS server.