# PHP 5.4.16 - mcrypt installation error

Tags: php, opencart, plesk

Please help to solve the problem with php-mcrypt for Opencart [image: Opencart installation]

```
user> yum -y install php-mcrypt

Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
PHP52_17                                                 | 2.9 kB     00:00     
PHP53_17                                                 | 2.9 kB     00:00     
PLESK_17_0_17-extras                                     | 2.9 kB     00:00     
PLESK_17_PHP54                                           | 2.9 kB     00:00     
PLESK_17_PHP55                                           | 2.9 kB     00:00     
PLESK_17_PHP56                                           | 2.9 kB     00:00     
PLESK_17_PHP70                                           | 2.9 kB     00:00     
PLESK_17_PHP71                                           | 2.9 kB     00:00     
base                                                     | 3.6 kB     00:00     
epel/x86_64/metalink                                     |  20 kB     00:00     
epel                                                     | 4.3 kB     00:00     
extras                                                   | 3.4 kB     00:00     
remi-safe                                                | 2.9 kB     00:00     
updates                                                  | 3.4 kB     00:00     
(1/16): PHP53_17/primary_db                                |  13 kB   00:00     
(2/16): PLESK_17_PHP56/primary_db                          |  13 kB   00:00     
(3/16): PLESK_17_PHP70/primary_db                          |  13 kB   00:00     
(4/16): PLESK_17_PHP71/primary_db                          |  13 kB   00:00     
(5/16): PHP52_17/primary_db                                |  13 kB   00:00     
(6/16): PLESK_17_PHP54/primary_db                          |  13 kB   00:00     
(7/16): PLESK_17_0_17-extras/primary_db                    |  26 kB   00:00     
(8/16): PLESK_17_PHP55/primary_db                          |  13 kB   00:00     
(9/16): base/7/x86_64/group_gz                             | 155 kB   00:00     
(10/16): base/7/x86_64/primary_db                          | 5.6 MB   00:00     
(11/16): epel/x86_64/group_gz                              | 150 kB   00:00     
(12/16): epel/x86_64/updateinfo                            | 748 kB   00:00     
(13/16): extras/7/x86_64/primary_db                        | 151 kB   00:00     
(14/16): epel/x86_64/primary_db                            | 5.9 MB   00:00     
(15/16): remi-safe/primary_db                              | 725 kB   00:00     
(16/16): updates/7/x86_64/primary_db                       | 5.6 MB   00:00     
Determining fastest mirrors
 * epel: mirror.nl.leaseweb.net
 * remi-safe: remi.mirror.wearetriple.com
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-mcrypt.x86_64 0:5.3.3-5.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php(zend-abi) = 20090626 for package: php-mcrypt-5.3.3-5.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: php(api) = 20090626 for package: php-mcrypt-5.3.3-5.el6.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: php-mcrypt-5.3.3-5.el6.x86_64 (epel)
       Requires: php(zend-abi) = 20090626
       Installed: php-common-5.4.16-42.el7.x86_64 (@base)
           php(zend-abi) = 20100525-64
Error: Package: php-mcrypt-5.3.3-5.el6.x86_64 (epel)
       Requires: php(api) = 20090626
       Installed: php-common-5.4.16-42.el7.x86_64 (@base)
           php(api) = 20100412-64
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

PHP version :

```
php -v
PHP 5.4.16 (cli) (built: Nov  6 2016 00:29:02) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2013 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies
with the ionCube PHP Loader v4.6.0, Copyright (c) 2002-2014, by ionCube Ltd.
```

php.ini:

```
[mcrypt]
; For more information about mcrypt settings see http://php.net/mcrypt-module-open
; Directory where to load mcrypt algorithms
; Default: Compiled in into libmcrypt (usually /usr/local/lib/libmcrypt)
;mcrypt.algorithms_dir=

; Directory where to load mcrypt modes
; Default: Compiled in into libmcrypt (usually /usr/local/lib/libmcrypt)
;mcrypt.modes_dir=
```

I also tried to add in php.ini :

```
extension=/usr/lib64/libmcrypt.so.4.4.8  - error
extension=mcrypt.so - can't load
```

There only two files in lib64 folder :

```
libmcrypt.so.4
libmcrypt.so.4.4.8
```

No modules with mcrypt in /lib64/php/modules :

```
curl.so                      ioncube_loader_lin_5.4.so  phar.so
dom.so                       ioncube_loader_lin_5.5.so  remi-release-6.rpm
epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm  json.so                    sqlite3.so
fileinfo.so                  mbstring.so                sw-engine
gd.so                        mysqli.so                  wddx.so
imap.so                      mysql.so                   xmlreader.so
ioncube_loader_lin_5.1.so    pdo_mysql.so               xmlwriter.so
ioncube_loader_lin_5.2.so    pdo.so                     xsl.so
ioncube_loader_lin_5.3.so    pdo_sqlite.so              zip.so
```

I also tried solutions from [https://stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17109818/install-php-mcrypt-on-centos-6)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution that helped me:

```
yum clean all
yum remove epel-release
yum install epel-release 
yum install php-mcrypt
```